# Is function $f:\{1,2\}\rightarrow\{1\}$ continuous?

Tags: functions, continuity

Under "regular" topology in $\mathbb{R}$, is function $f:\{1,2\}\rightarrow\{1\}$ continuous? Here $f$ is a function defined on $\{1,2\}$ and $f(1)=f(2)=1$.

I think it is. According to the definition of continuity, the pre-image of any open set is open. The only open set in this case is $\phi$, the empty set, and the pre-image is also $\phi$. Thus, $f$ is open. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What have you tried so far? For instance, what can you say about the topology of the set $\{1\}$, and what does this imply for this function?

Comment: @Martin R The domain here isn't a singleton

Comment: @JeanMarie: The question was changed after my closing vote.

Comment: @Martin R I understand. Always a disturbing situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the open set $\{1\}$ whose pre-image is the entire domain which is open. So the function is indeed continuous.

Comment: Why $\{1\}$ is open? Open set means it contain a open ball in the real line. But $\{1\}$ does not contain a open ball.. right?

Comment: No. I am assuming you don't have experience in topology. For a function $f:X\to Y$ to be continuous, we talk about open sets in $Y$, not some superset of $Y$. So we see subsets of $\{1\}$ which are open with respect to $\{1\}$, not necessarily with respect to $\Bbb R$. Note that there is only one open ball in $\{1\}$, and that is $\{1\}$ itself no matterwhich metric you use. This is because for any $\varepsilon>0,B(1,\varepsilon)=\{x\in\{1\}:d(x,1)<\varepsilon\}=\{1\}$. Likewise $\{1,2\}$ is open in $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Perfect. My understanding here is that continuity of a function $f$ is with respect to the topology of the image of $f$.

Comment: A slight correction: we use the topology on the codomain of $f$.